# Is multiple polynomial regression possible in python?

Tags: python, regression

Good day! I'd be appreciate if someone could guide me through the doubts below.

I'm working on a predictive modelling where I have two independent variables/predictors and one dependent variable.

Most resources of multiple regression only refers to linear regression, yet, the predictors I have are non-linear.

Is it possible to have:
y = z + ax1 + bx1^2 + cx2 + xc2^2
?

Let's say

```
X = [[2.64 0.96]
 [3.75 0.88]
 [3.74 0.75]
 [6.51 1.27]]


Y = [[0.77]
 [1.12]
 [1.12]
 [1.23]]
```

I know prediction for multiple linear regression is `regr.predict([[new_x1], [new_x2]])`. What about multiple polynomial regression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`PolynomialFeatures`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) from `sklearn.preprocessing` in order to generate the higher order terms. Then you can fit your model on the transformed data.

```
X = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2).fit_transform(X)
...  # use the new X to fit the model
```